# Determine value in range, inject to HTML to be used in CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to show users what package they are, based on how many items they have in their cart. The code works, but I'm wondering if anything can be improved.

```
function new_thing (){


//decleare variables
global $x_subs;
$lim01 = get_option(woomps_limit01);
$lim02 = get_option(woomps_limit02);
$lim03 = get_option(woomps_limit03);
$x = $x_subs;
$plugin_url =(plugins_url("/", __FILE__ ));

//set CSS class based on value of $x 
if  ($x >= 1 && $x < $lim02) {
    $active1 = "fb-sub-active";
    $active2 = "fb-sub-deactive";
    $active3 = "fb-sub-deactive";
} else if ($x >= $lim02 && $x < $lim03) {
    $active1 = "fb-sub-deactive";
    $active2 = "fb-sub-active";
    $active3 = "fb-sub-deactive";
} else if ($x >= $lim03) {
    $active1 = "fb-sub-deactive";
    $active2 = "fb-sub-deactive";
    $active3 = "fb-sub-active";
} else {
    $active1 = "fb-sub-deactive";
    $active2 = "fb-sub-deactive";
    $active3 = "fb-sub-deactive";
}


//generate the content that will be displayed
$content = <<<EOD

<div class="fb-sub-img-holder">
<img src="{$plugin_url}/images/subscription_pack_1.png" class="fb-img fb-sub-table1 {$active1}"></img>
<img src="{$plugin_url}/images/subscription_pack_2.png" class="fb-img fb-sub-table2 {$active2}"></img>
<img src="{$plugin_url}/images/subscription_pack_3.png" class="fb-img fb-sub-table3 {$active3}"></img>
<p>{$x_subs}</p>
</div>

EOD;

return $content;
}
```

```css
.fb-sub-img-holder {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.fb-img {
    width: 30%;

.fb-sub-active {
    width: 50%;
}
.fb-sub-deactive {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is `$lim01` never used?  Is it always equal to 1?

Only one of the subscription packs applies, if at all.  You should first make it clear which subscription pack applies.

```
$subscription_pack = (($x >= $lim03) ? 3 :
                     (($x >= $lim02) ? 2 :
                     (($x >= $lim01) ? 1 : NULL)));
# Note: inactive rather than deactive
$active1 = $active2 = $active3 = 'fb-sub-inactive';
if ($subscription_pack == 1) { $active1 = 'fb-sub-active'; }
if ($subscription_pack == 2) { $active2 = 'fb-sub-active'; }
if ($subscription_pack == 3) { $active3 = 'fb-sub-active'; }
```

I also suggest reworking the CSS so that you can drop the `fb-sub-inactive` class altogether.

Comment: This was so much simpler. And you are right, $Lim01 is not used for this functionality. Thank you very much, I learned a lot from implementing it. I only changed the operators so it gave out the MY expected result:
The reason I have the inactive CSS there is to put a transparency on deactive subscription package. But maybe this can be the default state or use the :not(.fb-sub-active). Hemmm… will try it out.

Comment: You also gave me a lesson on " and ' :)